# Is there a preferred solution to paus between audiofiles?

Tags: android, timer, wait

I'm a pistol shooter, and often practice by my self, so i made an app to give me the commands and keep track on time.
In my app i have four mp3 files.
 When i press start button the first file says: "*Ten seconds left*" and here i have `SystemClock.sleep(7000)`.

Second file says: "*Ready?*" and here i have `SystemClock.sleep(3000)`.
Third file says: "*Fire*". Depending on what value i have selected in a spinner, there is a `SystemClock.sleep(xxxx)`
Fourth file says: "*Cease fire*".

Now for my question: is `SystemClock.sleep()` the best solution for this? Seems to be somewhat unreliable. I have fool around with Thread.sleep and public void run. public void run did not work at all for me, or i did something wrong. That code does not exist anymore.

Comment: You should use `Timer`.

Comment: You should use `Handler().postDelayed`

Comment: @Rahul Sharma, finally got it. took about 2h of testing, but now i't works as supposed.